# Timer and Index

Tags: flutter

I want to make a continuous timer and add +1 to the variable and when the variable have value > 2, the value reset to 0

i have tried to make it, and i print everytime the code executed.
the output like this

```
1
2
3
2
3
3
3
3
```

My code

```
checkTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer t) {
        if(this._slideIndex > 2) {
          this._slideIndex = 0;
          controller.move(_slideIndex);
          print('$_slideIndex');
        } else {
          this._slideIndex++;
          controller.move(this._slideIndex);
          print('$_slideIndex');
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you add more code ?

Comment: Solved, thanks @diegoveloper